# Rails 3.1.rc1 Image Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to implement Rails 3.1 in my project, but none of my image_tags are working.

I really need nested has_many :through, which is why I choose to upgrade.

I know that images/javascripts/stylesheets should now go into app/assets/

However due to complications with my theme, I would like to keep them in public/

How would I go about doing so?

The image_tag, javascript_include_tag, and stylesheet_tag are looking only in the assets directory.

#### Console Output Example

```
Started GET "/assets/icons/small/white/Alarm%20Bell.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-27 11:04:48 -0400

Served asset /icons/small/white/Alarm%20Bell.png - 404 Not Found  (0.00488s)  (pid 1656)
```

That file is really located in "public/images/icons/small/white/Alarm Bell.png"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

In application.rb, at the bottom, set the asset pipeline to false.